# Delete rows from a Table when 2 specific columns are both zeros

Tags: matlab, rows

I'm trying to delete rows of a table, when both values of 2 specific columns are equal to zeros. I've tried to use `ismember(col1 & col2, 0),:)=[];` but it deletes the rows when only one of the column is zero.

Ideally, i would also like to do the opposite: delete every rows where the cells of these 2 columns aren't both zero. 
I know it would be easier if I wasn't using a table, unfortunately there is some needed variables that aren't numeric.

It would be great if you know a way to do what i need with a table.

Cheers

Comment: The logic is `(col1 == 0) & (col2 == 0)`.

Comment: Thanks! ```T(ismember(col1, 0) & ismember(col2,0),:)=[];```worked fine.